# Showing the Haar wavelet is a complete and orthonormal sequence within $L_2[0,1]$

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis, orthonormal

I define the mother Haar wavelet to be:
     \begin{align}
  \phi(t) = \begin{cases} 1 &\mbox{if } 0 \leq t < 1/2 \\ 
 -1 & \mbox{if } 1/2 \leq t \leq 1 \\
 0 &\mbox{otherwise}. \end{cases} 
  \end{align}
     Now, we have that the sequence of rescaled wavelets is:

$$
  \phi_n(t) = 2^{j/2} \phi(2^jt - k), \quad n = 2^j + k.
$$

Basically, we have that any integer $n$ can be uniquely written as $2^j + k$ for some $j \geq 0$ and $0 \leq k < 2^j$.

From here, I would like to show that $\phi_n$ is a complete and orthonormal sequence within $L_2 [0,1]$.

The orthonormal part is trivial for me, however, to show that it is also complete, I would like to use Parseval's Theorem.

Essentially, it claims that for any orthonormal sequence in $L_2 [0,1]$, if the only element $x \in L_2 [0,1]$ that satisfies $E(x\cdot\phi_n) =0$ for all $n$ is $x=0$, then the finite linear combinations of the functions $\{\phi_n\}$ form a dense subset of $L_2 [0,1]$. Then by definition, if the finite linear combinations of the functions $\{\phi_n\}$ form a dense subset of $L_2 [0,1]$, we have that it is a complete orthonormal sequence.

I start this by first choosing $x \in L_2 [0,1]$. Then, I have that $E(\phi_n(t)\cdot x) = E(2^{j/2} \phi(2^jt - k)\cdot x)$ (where $E$ is the expectation). Here, I want to show that this is $0$ only if $x=0$. However, I am not sure how to handle the expectation, and am not sure with what I am integrating to. Does anyone have a hint or know if my approach in using Parseval's Theorem is the right way to go? thanks!

Add-on: The version of Parseval I am using is from Stochastic Calculus and Financial Applications by Steele:

[image: Parseval's Theorem]

Comment: What is $E$? And which version of Parseval do you want to use?

Comment: It is expectation and I included an image of it.

Comment: This is certainly a weird way of thinking about it, but it's enlightening. Personally, I would approach it via the last one.

Comment: You could calculate the Fourier transform of each $\phi_n$ (i.e., the sequence of Fourier coefficients) and show that all these are complete in $\ell^2(\mathbb Z)$.

Comment: Thanks, my question is if it is even showable by b), is it functionally showable